# How to solve this rust lifetime bound issue of SDL2?

Tags: rust, sdl-2

I'm trying to render some font using sdl2 ttf. The type of Font type in sdl2 has a lifetime dependency on the context using PhantomData. I find it very difficult to use. Here's the the minimal code I'm trying to use.

main.rs

```
extern crate sdl2;

use sdl2::ttf::{self, Font};
use sdl2::ttf::Sdl2TtfContext;

struct App<'ttf> {
    ctx: Sdl2TtfContext,
    glyph_renderer: GlyphRenderer<'ttf>,
}

impl<'ttf> App<'ttf> {
    fn render(&self) {}
}

struct GlyphRenderer<'ttf> {
    font: Font<'ttf, 'static>,
}

fn main() {
    let ttf_context = ttf::init().unwrap();

    let font = ttf_context.load_font("./assets/Supermercado-Regular.ttf", 50).unwrap();
    let glyph_renderer = GlyphRenderer { font };

    let app = App {
        ctx: ttf_context,
        glyph_renderer,
    };

    app.render();
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "demo-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["clojure"]

[dependencies.sdl2]
version = "0.31.0"
default-features = false
features = ["ttf"]
```

1. ttf_context is moved. I can solve this one, but by changing code in a ugly way.
2. Font has lifetime bound on context. Cannot fix this one.

This documentation contains the declaration of `Sdl2TtfContext` and `Font`, should you find it useful. [DOC](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Tim, I updated the code. Now it includes a shortest code example.

Comment: Can you please add the error output?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I am able to fix this issue by moving context creation to the outer scope. It cannot be put on a struct.

```
fn start(ttf_context: &Sdl2TtfContext) {
    let font = ttf_context.load_font("./assets/Supermercado-Regular.ttf", 50).unwrap();
    let glyph_renderer = GlyphRenderer { font };

    let app = App {
        glyph_renderer,
    };

    app.render();
}

fn main() {
    let ttf_context = ttf::init().unwrap();
    start(&ttf_context);
}
```