# Is there a way to have a struct contain a reference that might no longer be valid?

Tags: rust

Like some kind of `Box` that holds the reference to the value or something?  I'd have to check whether the value is still alive or not before reading it, like when a `Option` is pattern matched.

A mock example:

```
struct Whatever {
    thing: AliveOrNot<i32>,
}
fn main() {
    let mut w = Whatever { thing: Holder::Empty };
    w.thing = AliveOrNot::new(100);
    match w.thing {
        Empty => println!("doesn't exist"),
        Full(value) => println!("{}", value),
    }
}
```

The exact case is that I'm using a sdl2 [`Font`](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/ttf/struct.Font.html) and I want to store instances of that struct in another struct. I don't want to do something like this because the `Parent` would have to live exactly as long as the `Font`:

```
struct Font<'a, 'b> {
    aa: &'a i32,
    bb: &'b i32,
}
struct Parent<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    f: &'c Font<'a, 'b>
}
```

What I want is for the `Parent` to work regardless of whether that field is still alive or not.

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in [`std::rc::Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) or [`std::sync::Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Weak.html):

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

struct Whatever {
    thing: Weak<i32>,
}

impl Whatever {
    fn do_it(&self) {
        match self.thing.upgrade() {
            Some(value) => println!("{}", value),
            None => println!("doesn't exist"),
        }
    }
}

fn its_dead_jim() -> Whatever {
    let owner = Rc::new(42);
    let thing = Rc::downgrade(&owner);

    let whatever = Whatever { thing };
    whatever.do_it();

    whatever
}

fn main() {
    let whatever = its_dead_jim();
    whatever.do_it();
}
```

```
42
doesn't exist
```

There is **no** way to do this in safe Rust using non-`'static` references. A huge point of Rust's references is that it's impossible to refer to invalid values.

- You could leak the memory, creating a `&'static i32`, but that's not sustainable if you need to do this multiple times.
- You could use `unsafe` code and deal with raw pointers that have no notion of lifetimes. You then assume the responsibility of ensuring you don't introduce memory unsafety.

See also:

- [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45674479/155423)
- [Situations where Cell or RefCell is the best choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30831037/155423)
- [Is there a shared pointer with a single strong owner and multiple weak references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50751606/155423)
- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)
- [How to convert a String into a &'static str](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23975391/155423)
- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- [How to solve this rust lifetime bound issue of SDL2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49747073/155423)
- [Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41270052/155423)

Comment: How would I specify the type with the lifetimes then? Wouldn't the Parent struct have to live as long as the Font struct if I do something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a596a2d92b38ee4433fc1fb0e0f9f9e5 ?

Comment: @PabloTatoRamos with that example, `Parent` would not be allowed to outlive whatever establishes the `'a` and `'b` lifetimes, [but the `Font` can be dropped](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09ed93dad3fd8492eddc36cba07a6aef).

Comment: I think we are not understanding each other. the 'a and 'b lifetimes are there because they have meaning to Font, not because they have meaning to Parent. I specifically don't want to drop Parent when those lifetimes are over.

Comment: the point is I want the Parent struct to not know if Font exists or not. I don't know how to explain it better 

Comment: or rather it might know. it's just that it could be any of the two states.

Comment: I don't particularly care if the answer is to write unsafe code. I'd just like to know where to look into

Comment: @PabloTatoRamos It isn't a matter of if you can write `unsafe` code to do this - it would also be _unsound_. Even looking at a dangling pointer is undefined behaviour, so your best option is to use a `Weak`, which is specifically designed to model the idea of a reference that might not be valid anymore.

Comment: @Pablo You *cannot* have an invalid reference, even in unsafe code. Creating one is instant-UB. The reason lifetimes exist is to prove this. It sounds like you have only at best a vague idea of how you want the problem to be solved; Rust does not have any mechanism that would allow a `Parent` to be informed that it should be invalidated, or indeed any mechanism that would allow a `Parent` to know that it *is* invalidated. **References are always valid.**

Comment: @PeterHall I did not understand what you're trying to say. Shepmaster already told me to use Weak, it's higher up in the thread

Comment: If the answer is "it is impossible", is there a blog post or a documentation explaining why that's the case? I'm curious 

Comment: @PabloTatoRamos It is impossible. I don't know about blog posts, but I think it is summed up pretty well by [trentcl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508705/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-struct-contain-a-reference-that-might-no-longer-be-vali/60508832?noredirect=1#comment107050937_60508832): _"You cannot have an invalid reference, even in unsafe code. Creating one is instant-UB."_